# Who wrote the Sephardi hoshanot?

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, sukkot, authorship

Who wrote the Sephardi hoshanot? The name יוסף בר יצחק is all over the acrostics, but who was he?

Comment: It's quite possible we won't ever know who he was. Oftentimes, we don't know who wrote a _piyyut_, even a common one, and even if we do know his name, sometimes we know little about him beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

See here about the history of the hosha'anot(in hebrew), specifically the section about Sephardic tradition:
 https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA

And here about R' Yosef bar Yitzchak(also in hebrew): https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8

They originated over the years in Israel, Spain, Italy, and Yemen by different Chachamim and poets including R' Elazar hakalir, R' Sa'adia Gaon, and R' Yosef bar R' Yitzchak.